# Class not being created in Powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell

So I'm trying to create a JavaScript function inside Powershell and I use a class called "sc":

```
$language = "JScript"


function Create-ScriptEngine()
{
  param([string]$language = $null, [string]$code = $null)
  if ( $language )
  {
    $sc = New-Object -ComObject ScriptControl
    $sc.Language = $language
    if ( $code )
    {
      $sc.AddCode($code);
    }
    $sc.CodeObject;
  }
}


$jscode = @"
function jslen(s)
{
  return s.length;
}
"@


$sc -ne $null
$js = Create-ScriptEngine "JScript" $jscode;
$str = "abcd";
$js.jslen($str);
```

Using $sc -ne $null I can check if the class is made and it just provides me with "false".
Not really sure whats causing this.

I'm using powershell 5 if anyone is wondering.

Comment: Your code works here on PS5.1x86 (not x64, naturally, as msscript.ocx is 32-bit only) except for the obvious out-of-scope use of `$sc`.

Comment: Being new to powershell, I've quite literally just realized that x64 does not have msscript.ocx. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `$sc` is limited to the `Create-ScriptEngine` function, so trying to call it outside of the function will result in null.

Also, your `$js` appears to be null too, because your function isn't returning anything. I assume that you'll want to put `return $sc` within the `Create-ScriptEngine` function to get your code working.