# Getting errors running JS in powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell, scriptcontrol

So I'm trying to run this javascript function in powershell using ScriptControl.

```
function Create-Script()
{
  param([string]$code = $null);
  if ( $code ) {
    $sc = New-Object -ComObject ScriptControl;
    $sc.Language = "JScript";
    $sc.AddCode($code);
    $sc.CodeObject;
  }
}

$jscode = @"
function jslen(s) {
  return s.length;
}
"@

$js = Create-Script $jscode;
$str = "abcd";
$contents = $js.jslen($str);
```

And I get this error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.At line:21 char:1
+ $js.jslen($str);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Any ideas on whats going on?

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39253406/3959875)? My comment is the same: it works for me on x86. Just make sure msscript.ocx is registered: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msscript.ocx`

Comment: I've did the registering for msscript.ocx and as far as i can tell it is registered. The script should work, but it isn't. I used elevated cmd and did "regsvr32 msscript.ocx".

Comment: It's better to register using full paths.

Comment: Ok so I've tried using full paths now as well and that still hasn't made any difference.

Comment: Does scriptcontrol object exist on x64?

Comment: @wOxxOm It works for a while in 32 bit powershell, but then seems to crash:  `Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))`